# How to build native C++ apps with HTML/CSS UI?

Tags: c++, html, css, user-interface, desktop-application

Is it possible to develop a C++ program while using HTML and CSS for the user interface? I know about programming with Javascript using a Webkit container, but I am really interested in C++ development.

I felt in love with C# WPF when I developed under Windows, but now I moved to Linux and I haven't found a good tool for using markup for interfaces. For this, I would like to mix HTML and CSS, which are very lightweight and easy to use, with C++ code, with something like WPF.

Oh, one more thing: I'm looking for desktop development, not web.

Comment: You can build cross-platform desktop apps with C++ backend and HTML/CSS/JS frontend using Molybden SDK: https://teamdev.com/molybden

You can even call C++ functions from JavaScript and vice versa with automatic types conversion. Read more at https://docs.molybden.io/development/javascript-to-cpp.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. What you want is a C++ web framework. You could start by looking at [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main)—a Free High Performance Web Development Framework (not a CMS) aimed for Rapid Web Application Development.

**Edit**: After the question has been clarified, I think [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) would be a good fit for your needs.

You can achieve the same functionality by embedding WebKit (or Gecko) but as far as I know that is exactly what Awesomium does behind the scenes.

An alternative is [librocket](https://github.com/libRocket/libRocket)—a C++ interface middleware package designed for game applications. As you can guess from the description it is a good fit for games or real-time applications.

Comment: But would this compile for an executable? I'm looking for desktop, not web.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to fire up a browser and navigate to http://localhost/ and use the interface of your application? Or do you want the user to open an executable and be presented with the web interface?

Comment: @RobertDinu I think he wants to build a desktop application with C++ and create the user interface with HTML/CSS

Comment: I can see how this would save a lot of time. Would this approach lead to issues at any point?

Comment: @expiredninja the only potential issue I can see is the need for native elements, but they offer drop in components like Unity. I imagine you could extend it to do what you need.

Comment: Check out Coherent Labs' Gameface - https://coherent-labs.com/products/coherent-gameface/. Even though it's billed as game UI "middleware", you can build cross-platform apps with it.

Answer (score 42):

[Sciter](http://sciter.com) is exactly that - embeddable HTML/CSS engine with C/C++ API. Compact and multi-platform.

And check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859098/Sciter-multiplatform-embeddable-HTML-CSS-scripting).

Sciter has the same [feature set as WPF](http://sciter.com/wpf-vs-sciter/) but uses HTML/CSS instead of XAML and uses native API.

Features out of the box:

- HTML, CSS, SVG, aPNG (animated PNGs), image sprites,
- `<plaintext>` - editor with syntax highlighting,
- `<htmlarea>` - WYSIWYG HTML editor,
- `<frame type=pager>` - print preview and HTML/CSS print,
- animations,
- HTTP client, REST/JSON client, WebSocket's, DataSockets,
- etc.

The same application with Sciter UI running on Windows, MacOS and Linux from the same sources:

[image]

Disclaimer: I am an author of Sciter Engine.

**2021 update:** you can also use [**Sciter.JS**](https://github.com/c-smile/sciter-js-sdk) that is version of Sciter that uses standard JavaScript (ES2020) script engine.

Comment: I am a beginner in c++ but I find the documentation scanty and scary for beginners..the documentation should start with how to run the demos in codeblocks or even a shell to see if it works ...Kindly add some more marketing effort in your project

Comment: @repzero check this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859098/Sciter-multiplatform-embeddable-HTML-CSS-scripting , I think it is suitable for C++ beginners.

Comment: @repzero As of codeblocks, just open {sciter-sdk}/demos/usciter/usciter.cbp in that IDE, select Release64 target and click on "Build and Run" button - you should see the app running.

Comment: @c-smile thanks for some guidance here.when I tried to running the project in codeblocks I get a fatal error "gtk/gtk.h no such file or directory" this error was emanating from the include statement in the "sciter-x-types.h" header file...I am running debian jessie..I  have a folder named gtk which contains gtk.h file. this folder is located in '/user/include/gtk-2.o/gtk'..any advice?

Comment: On Linux Sciter requires GTK3. If you want to build samples then you will need gtk development package, try `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

Comment: Very interesting project. For my need there is only one concern. Is there way to pass image of OpenCV (cv::Mat) format to webpage without conversion it to base64 format?

Comment: You can extend Sciter by native functions and events and use that from scripts on the page. So you can create instance of cv::Mat in your native code and pass it with methods to script to manipulate it.

Answer (score 14):

I think [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) would be a nice addition to the other answers.

It uses NodeJS to run a Webkit Window. Electron itself is only html/css/js, but you can use any Node Module within your Electron App - including custom, natively compiled C++ code. A possible Module to embed your C++ code would be node-gyp.

Be aware, however, that this workflow may include a little bit more JS than you would have with the other answers.

My favourite text editor, [Atom](https://atom.io/), was made with Electron.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) to embed HTML5 content in your app.
You'll get might and speed of Chromium and ability to build GUI apps the same way you develop web applications.

Comment: Might and speed of Chromium ... and size ;)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest checking out [Ultralight HTML UI Engine](https://ultralig.ht/)
Not Open Source, Available for C++. OpenGL and DirectX rendering supported.

> Ultralight is the lighter, faster option to integrate HTML UI in your
> C++ app.

It's made by the creator of Awesomium, who unfortunately decided to delete Awesomium.

If you need something more heavy weight I recommend taking a look at [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Tutorial). It’s a very powerful (and open source) tool.

Comment: It being closed source is very, very unfortunate, considering what Awesomium was capable of :(

Comment: I gave Ultralight a try but failed. Couldn't even run the Browser sample due to lib-not-found errors. The containing folder is definitely in my PATH variable. 
Tried to compile the Basic App but didn't succeed. Compiler couldn't find class Settings which is nowhere declared as I could prove using grep.
(Ubuntu 18.4)

Comment: @testalucida You can seek support at Ultralight’s Slack workspace.

Answer (score 4):

### I would suggest [RmlUI](https://github.com/mikke89/RmlUi)

Its an active fork of librocket with more features. Its very modular, you can handle rendering, event handling and user input yourself (or copy one from provided examples).

[image: Demo Game Menu Screenshot]

Note: RmlUI doesn't support full HTML5/CSS3 specifications, but only a subset of it. Animations are supported tho.